# Xen on Ubuntu Server 18.04 stuck after boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, xen

I have setup an Ubuntu Server 18.04 Machine where I installed Xen Hypervisor via the following:

```
sudo apt install xen-hypervisor-4.9-x64
```

Installation went fine, but after reboot (after POST and kernel loading) screen goes blank ( not dark, but blank) and the system locks up/hangs. This happens with Xen Kernel. If I boot via Ubuntu's kernel (Xen-less), it continues to boot and I get my login screen.

At that point I can't reboot (ctrl+alt+del), I have to pull the power plug to shut it off.

The system is old, but it supports VT-x. Any ideas as to what might be wrong?

Regards